# Fixed Byte Slice to String Conversion - ignore nulls

Tags: string, go

Is there is efficient way to convert a fixed byte slice to a string without adding null characters to the string?

The traditional way to convert a string from a byte slice is the following:

```
out := string(b[STRIDX:STRIDX+STRLEN])
```

While this returns a string, the length is always equal to the byte slice length. So while the string looks normal on a `Print` statement it is still referencing potentiality null values.This has some very odd effects if you append characters to this string.

Right now i scan the byte slice for nulls to limit the byte slice i feed to `string`. Not very pretty or efficient.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/hOoaqCOoFl0

Comment: What part of this code is causing problems with efficiency? `bytes.Index` is going to be the quickest way to find the first null byte.

Comment: I have to import the `bytes` package only for this operation, that is the inefficiency. Also I would expect that this should be fixable with `builtins`.

Comment: You probably already have various bytes package functions built into your program, since it's used throughout the std library. You can loop over the slice and find the byte yourself, but the `bytes.IndexByte` function is written in assembly since it's used quite often. It's relatively uncommon to use arrays like this, so there's no real reason to have something built into the language itself.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple function:

```
func CToGoString(b []byte) string {
    i := bytes.IndexByte(b, 0)
    if i < 0 {
        i = len(b)
    }
    return string(b[:i])
}
```

For your example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func CToGoString(b []byte) string {
    i := bytes.IndexByte(b, 0)
    if i < 0 {
        i = len(b)
    }
    return string(b[:i])
}

const (
    BUFLEN = 50
    STRLEN = 10
    STRIDX = 10
)

func main() {
    test := "test"
    b := [BUFLEN]byte{}
    fmt.Printf("Original\n\tString: '%+v' with length '%d'\n", test, len(test))

    copy(b[10:], []byte(test))

    s := CToGoString(b[STRIDX : STRIDX+STRLEN])
    fmt.Printf("Unpacking with []byte()\n\tString: '%+v' with length '%d' Buf:%+v\n", s, len(s), []byte(s))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mH3CBdM6eG_l

Output:

```
Original
    String: 'test' with length '4'
Unpacking with []byte()
    String: 'test' with length '4' Buf:[116 101 115 116]
```